# I have a transparent image set for my logo but it still shows with a white background, how do I make it transparent?

Tags: css, wordpress

My website is http://snacksandsocks.com/ I have downloaded a transparent image of my logo I got off Fivver from Canva. Now when I put that image into the logo section on my Wordpress it still is showing with a white background. I think it might be the theme from all the research I've done. I was just wondering if I could use CSS to get rid of it?

Comment: I see that, you have white background image http://snacksandsocks.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/12-01-scaled.jpg

Comment: Your image doesn’t have a transparent background because you saved it as jpg, which add a white background as default. Go back to canvas and if you don’t have a background on your image, try to save it as PNG.

Answer (score -1):

Because you image is a jpeg image which does not support transparency. Try to save it in png.